# Python - Set file EOF

Tags: python-2.7, eof, file-writing

Say, for some reason, I have a 1 TB file. In Python, if I wanted to add 10 bytes, I could just seek to the end, and write a 10 byte string. However, say I'd like to cut 10 bytes off the end of it. Obviously, it would take a ridiculous amount of time (and there may not even be HDD space) to copy this file without the excess 10 bytes, then delete the old one.

In c++ for Windows, there's a function, [`SetEndOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531(v=vs.85).aspx), that lets me change file size to something smaller without file rewriting.

Is there a similar function in python that will do this? I've researched and cannot find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I guess I hadn't looked hard enough: [`truncate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate)

```
f = open(fname)
f.seek(-10,2) # jump 10 bytes before end
f.truncate() # truncate it!!
f.close()
```